# Use Quick Create form instead of Edit form in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

In SugarCRM, we are receiving Emails directly in the Emails module. From these emails, we can manually create Cases by using the Quick Create feature.

This feature normally displays the QuickCreate form that we can edit in the Studio part of the edit panel. Here, my Edit form is different from my QuickCreate form.

However, in the Emails module, when I click on the Quick Create button to create a case, I see the full Edit form instead of the Quick Create form.

Does anyone have a solution to fix this please ?

I'm using SugarCE version 6.5.26, but I guess SuiteCRM has the same kind of issue/solution.

Comment: For this, you have to modify core files which can be non-upgrade safe.

Comment: @Star It's not a problem as the community edition of SugarCRM is no longer maintained, so there won't be any upgrade. Do you have any fix in mind ?

Comment: Checking the flow, hopefully there will be a way :)

Comment: It is calling file: modules/Emails/EmailUI.php, function=getQuickCreateForm, so if at line#1280, you change the metadata file from edit view to quick create then hopefully it will work for you. You might need to change the helper methods to reference it to quick create view. Give it a try!

Comment: I tried that already. The issue also I guess is that the `QuickCreate` template basically just includes the `EditView` template... So there seems to be no Quick Create template at all to be used.

Comment: quick create and edit uses same template but it is parsed on the basis of selected metadata

Comment: One quick hack, if you change "QuickCreate" in "quickcreatedefs.php" to "EditView" then it will prepare view according to the "quickcreatedefs.php" metadata.